# unresolved symbol vec_add_

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

First, my source programs are shown as follows:

**call_fun.f90**

```
program call_fun
use omp_lib
implicit none

integer, parameter :: N = 100
integer a(N), b(N), c(N)
integer i

do i = 1, N
    a(i) = i
    b(i) = i+1
end do

!$omp target
!$omp parallel do
do i = 1, N     
    call vec_add(a(i), b(i), c(i))
end do
!$omp end target

write(*,10) N, c(N)
10 format('c[', I4, ']=', I6)
end program
```

**vec_add.f90**

```
subroutine vec_add(a, b, c)
implicit none

integer a, b, c

c = a + b
end
```

Obviously, this two programs are simple, and I just for testing. Then, I use following commands to compile and link the programs:

```
gfortran -fopenmp -foffload=nvptx-none -c vec_add.f90 call_fun.f90
gfortran -fopenmp -foffload=nvptx-none call_fun.o vec_add.o -o call.x
```

finally, I received followed error reports:

```
unresolved symbol vec_add_
collect2: 错误：ld 返回 1
mkoffload: fatal error: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc returned 1 
exit status
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: 致命错误：/home/gjh/software/offload/install/libexec/gcc/x86_64- 
pc-linux-gnu/9.0.0//accel/nvptx-none/mkoffload 以返回值 1 退出
编译中断。
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: 错误：ld 返回 1
```

It seems that linker can't find vec_add_, but I don't know how to fix it. My GCC version is 9.0.0(20180605), and corresponding OpenMP version is 4.5. I don't know if it doesn't support the function call in the task construct, or some others reasons. Has anyone encountered such problem?

More detailed, I used following script to configure environment:

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# Build GCC with support for offloading to NVIDIA GPUs
#

work_dir=$HOME/software/offload
install_dir=$work_dir/install

# Location of the installed CUDA toolkit
cuda=/usr/local/cuda

# Build assembler and linking tools
cd $work_dir
git clone https://github.com/MentorEmbedded/nvptx-tools
cd nvptx-tools
./configure \
    --with-cuda-driver-include=$cuda/include \
    --with-cuda-driver-lib=$cuda/lib64 \
    --enable-languages="c,c++,fortran,lto" \
    --prefix=$install_dir
make clean
make
make install
cd ../

# Set up the GCC source tree
git clone https://github.com/MentorEmbedded/nvptx-newlib
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk gcc
cd gcc
contrib/download_prerequistes
ln -s ../nvptx-newlib/newlib newlib
cd ..
target=$(gcc/config.guess)

# Build nvptx GCC
mkdir build-nvptx-gcc
cd build-nvptx-gcc
../gcc/configure \
     --target=nvptx-none --with-build-time-tools=$install_dir/nvptx-none/bin \
     --enable-as-accelerator-for=$target \
     --disable-sjlj-exceptions \
     --enable-newlib-io-long-long \
     --enable-languages="c,c++,fortran,lto" \
     --prefix=$install_dir
make clean
make -j4
make install
cd ..

# Build host GCC
mkdir build-host-gcc
cd build-host-gcc
../gcc/configure \
    --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none \
    --with-cuda-driver-include=$cuda/include \
    --with-cuda-driver-lib=$cuda/lib64 \
    --disable-bootstrap \
    --disable-multilib \
    --enable-languages="c,c++,fortran,lto" \
    --prefix=$install_dir
make clean
make -j4
make install
cd ..
```

this script was written by other people, and I referenced to it. In addition, I set environment variables as follows.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64:/home/gjh/software/offload/install/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin:/home/gjh/software/offload/install/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I removed `-fopenmp -foffload=nvptx-none` from your commands and generated a run version using `-o call_test.exe` (on windows 7) and all worked ok. I suggest you confirm that, then introduce `-fopenmp` (without target), then introduce `target`

Comment: Yeah, me too. However, if I do not use the option "-fopenmp -foffload=nvptx-none", generated run program "call_test.exe" will only be executed in CPU and only one core. while my original intention is to execute program on GPU and use multi threads by "-fopenmp -foffload=nvptx-none".

Comment: The error message points to a custom built or manual binary download of GCC. How did you install GCC? Is your environment (variables `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc) set properly for that compiler?

Comment: I just edited my question more specifically, including to add my install way and environment configuration. Thanks for your reply.